# Best way to check if an Array of primitives contains all of the primitives in another Array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm looking for the best way to check if an Array of primitives contains all of the primitives in another Array in Java. For instance:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2};
int[] b = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
int[] c = new int[]{2,4,6};

containsAll(b, a); //true
containsAll(a, b); //false
containsAll(c, b); //false
```

Where containsAll is a function that check if inside the first parameter there is the second parameter!!! I don't want to convert my arrays of int in arrays of Integer in order to use the following method:

```
Arrays.asList(a).containsAll(Arrays.asList(b))
```

Because I think that if the arrays are huge, it would be a big waste of performance!!! But maybe I'm wrong and the best solution is that one... Have you got any idea?

Comment: If they are always guaranteed to be sorted you can use binary tree search.

Comment: Deconstruct the problem: What's the best way to find out if an array of primitives contains a given value? Then, repeat that for each value in the array you want to check until you run out (result = true) or don't find one (result = false).

Comment: You can write your own double for loop and bench it against the implementation you show, but you should do that yourself.

Comment: I think convert an int to an Integer is not bad. write a unit test with one million of int and check the performance.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(a).containsAll(Arrays.asList(b))` does NOT do what you expect when applied to an array of primitive.

Answer (score 1):

The `containsAll()` method from the Java collections framework effectively does the two nested loops, so you'll waste performance converting to `ArrayList<Integer>` or `Integer[]` with `Arrays.asList()` and using `containsAll()`.

Doing two nested loops over your `int[]` arrays yourself will definitely beat that.

And if you have additional information (e.g. sorted arrays, repeated use of the same arrays, typical sizes of the arrays), a more performant algorithm might be possible.